# Comparing React refs to set a class name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

So I am trying to set a className when an input is focused in React. I am using refs for that. I am also using React v16.8.3.

At the inputs className I am comparing the focused ref with the focused input. I added a test function and when I compare it in this function it works just fine. But for some reason I don't understand why it is not working in the className if/else.

I hope it is somewhat clear what I am trying to do.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function EditSocialmedia (props) {

  const [facebook, setFacebook] = useState(props.social.youtube);
  const [youtube, setYoutube] = useState(props.social.youtube);
  const [twitter, setTwitter] = useState(props.social.twitter);
  const [focusedElement, setFocusedElement] = useState(React.createRef());
  let refFacebook = React.createRef();
  let refYoutube = React.createRef();
  let refTwitter = React.createRef();

  function test () {
    console.log(focusedElement)
    console.log(refFacebook === focusedElement)
    console.log(refYoutube === focusedElement)
    console.log(refTwitter === focusedElement)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="hSmaller hthin">Social Media</h2>

      <input id={`facebook`}
             className={refFacebook === focusedElement ? "active" : ""}
             ref={(input) => refFacebook = input}
             value={facebook ? facebook : ""}
             onChange={() => {setFacebook(refFacebook.value)}}
             onFocus={() => setFocusedElement(refFacebook)}/>

      <input id={`youtube`}
             className={focusedElement === refYoutube ? "active" : ""}
             ref={(input) => refYoutube = input}
             value={youtube ? youtube : ""}
             onChange={() => {setYoutube(refYoutube.value)}}
             onFocus={() => setFocusedElement(refYoutube)}/>

      <input id={`twitter`}
             className={focusedElement === refTwitter ? "active" : ""}
             ref={(input) => refTwitter = input}
             value={twitter ? twitter : ""}
             onChange={() => {setTwitter(refTwitter.value)}}
             onFocus={() => setFocusedElement(refTwitter)}/>

      <div onClick={test}>Test</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EditSocialmedia;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I converted the function component to a class component at got it working like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class EditSocialmedia extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      facebook: "",
      youtube: "",
      twitter: "",
      focusedElement: React.createRef()
    };
  }

  render () {
    const {facebook, youtube, twitter} = this.props.social
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="hSmaller hthin">Social Media</h2>

        <input id={`facebook`}
               className={this.refFacebook === this.state.focusedElement ? "active" : ""}
               ref={(input) => this.refFacebook = input}
               value={facebook ? facebook : ""}
               onChange={() => {this.setState({facebook: this.refFacebook})}}
               onFocus={() => this.setState({focusedElement: this.refFacebook})}/>

        <input id={`youtube`}
               className={this.refYoutube === this.state.focusedElement ? "active" : ""}
               ref={(input) => this.refYoutube = input}
               value={youtube ? youtube : ""}
               onChange={() => {this.setState({youtube: this.refYoutube})}}
               onFocus={() => this.setState({focusedElement: this.refYoutube})}/>

        <input id={`twitter`}
               className={this.refTwitter === this.state.focusedElement ? "active" : ""}
               ref={(input) => this.refTwitter = input}
               value={twitter ? twitter : ""}
               onChange={() => {this.setState({twitter: this.refTwitter})}}
               onFocus={() => this.setState({focusedElement: this.refTwitter})}/>

      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default EditSocialmedia;
```

Answer (score 0):

`onFocus` changes the state and causes your component to rerender and change refs. `className` checks the wrong refs **during** render. And `test` checks the correct refs **after** the render.

Try calling `test` before `return`, inside `ref` setting and inside `onFocus` event.